# Problems with cloning a react app from github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, proxy, proxy-server

I am pretty new to javascript and react, I want to use this github https://github.com/bennychen27/LoL-Stats-Tracker.

I use Visual Studio Code.

How I tried it?

1. Downloaded the App as zip
2. Unpacked it
3. I have seen that this project includes a proxyserver and a client
4. Then I have seen, that there are in my opinion files missing within the client folder, because how I have learned, the proxyserver and the App have to get started in two separat Terminals.
5. So I have opened the unpacked folder in my visual Studio
6. I used `npm install` in the main directory
7. I deleted the client folder
8. I created a new client folder by using: `npx create-react-app client` in the main directorty
   9.Then I replaced the files in this client folder with the before deleted files of the before deleted client folder
9. I restartet my Visual Studio
10. I used `npm install` in the new client folder
11. Then I added the line `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",` in the package.json file of the client, because the server runs on port 4000
12. Then I used `npm start` in the main diectory and the client folder
13. Then the proxyserver started without problems
14. And the client showed this error `The react-scripts command is either misspelled or could not be found.`
15. So I used `npm install` again to fix that.
16. Then I used `npm start` in the client folder
17. Then the error `'React' must be in scope when using JSX` showed up
18. I added `import React, { Component }  from 'react';` in my app.js file
19. A new Error showed up `Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in .... Failed to compile.`
20. I used
    `npm install --save moment`
    `npm install --save react-moment`
    `npm install --save moment-timezone`
    after that in my client folder
21. After a new try to start this error showed up `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-select' in ...`
22. I used `npm i react-select` to fix that

Now I am gettig errors over and over again, so I want to ask you if anyone could tell me, how I can set this up correctly, because how I already said, I am new to react.

Comment: Add screenshot or details of the exact error so that the community can help you out currently based on your question no one has any idea what they need to fix !

Comment: OK, now it works, I only had to instal a few more things